# Problem with unicode Characters (arabic) in josm

Tags: shapefile, convert, josm

I'm using josm for converting a shapefile to .osm format. When I import the shapefile to josm the arabic characters do not show correctly (see the image below). The dbf of the shapefile shows the characters correctly . How can I solve the problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this ticket:

http://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/10214

you need to have a `.cpg` file along with the shapefile with the correct encoding written inside.

And a josm version that is less than 6 months old (when the bug was fixed).